# TypeScript: Why can't I assign a valid field of an object with type { a: "a", b: "b" }

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I created the following types from a constant array `<const>['a', 'b]`:

```ts
const paths = <const>['a', 'b']

type Path = typeof paths[number]

type PathMap = {
  [path in Path]: path
}
```

`Path` equals to `"a" | "b"`

`PathMap` equals to `{a: "a", b: "b"}`

Then the following code compiles fine:

```ts
const BASE_PATHS = paths.reduce((map: PathMap, p: Path) => {
  map['a'] = 'a'
  return map
}, <PathMap>{})
```

This also works:

```ts
const BASE_PATHS = paths.reduce((map: PathMap, p: Path) => {
  return { ...map, [p]: p }
}, <PathMap>{})
```

But the following code does not compile:

```ts
const BASE_PATHS = paths.reduce((map: PathMap, p: Path) => {
  map[p] = p
  return map
}, <PathMap>{})
```

Which gave me this error at `map[p] = p`:

`TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Why is this the case?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I believe second option is the best approach to stick with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because objects are contravariant in their key types.

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286) answer.

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

```js
const paths = ['a', 'b'] as const

type Path = typeof paths[number]

type PathMap = {
    [path in Path]: path
}

type a = 'a'
type b = 'b'

type c = a & b // never

{
    const BASE_PATHS = paths.reduce((map: PathMap, p: Path) => {
        let x = map[p]
        map[p] = p // same here
        return map
    }, {} as PathMap)
```

Intersection of `a` and `b` produces `never`.

If you remove `as const` from `paths` it will compile, because `string & string = string`

Btw, since you are using functional approach try to avoid object mutations.

[Here](https://catchts.com/mutations), in my blog, you can find more information about mutations in TS

Credits to **@aleksxor**

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) you can find official explanation

Comment: In complement to your answer. Here is [microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) the exact PR introduced this behaviour for indexed access types when union type converts into intersection when met on the target side of assignment.

Comment: @aleksxor thanks a lot for the link! I made an update of answer

Comment: Just checked your blog. Very good resources are available. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I am also in the process of advancing TS skills. I want to write a blog, a book on Typesript.

Comment: Don't forget to share the link to your blog

Comment: Sure, definitely

Answer (score 0):

This is because `map[p]` will give you either `a` or `b` and type of `a` or `b` is definitely a `string`. For type `Path`, as it is a union type, type string is `never` for `Path` because `Path` must satisfy `a` or `b`. You can do something like this

```
const BASE_PATHS = paths.reduce((map: PathMap, p: Path) => {
    // enforce the compiler to treat map[p] as one of Path
    (map[p] as Path) = p;
    return map;
}, {} as PathMap);
```