# TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never

Tags: typescript

I have got error `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.` in `result[key] = forms.${key};`

and don't understand how i can fix it. (without prefix everything is ok).
Why typescript considers `result[key]` as never?

```
export const InitialState = {
  login: {
    login: '',
    password: '',
    accept_terms: false,
  },
  forgot: {
    login: '',
    password: '',
  },
};

type FormsKey = keyof typeof InitialState;

type FormsMap = {
  [K in FormsKey]: `forms.${K}`
};

const keys = Object.keys(InitialState) as FormsKey[];
const forms: FormsMap = keys.reduce<FormsMap>((result, key) => {
  result[key] = `forms.${key}`;
  return result;
}, {} as FormsMap);

export default forms;
```

Comment: I believe your question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189542/typescript-why-cant-i-assign-a-valid-field-of-an-object-with-type-a-a-b/68190097#68190097)

Answer (score 0):

Because of `const forms: FormsMap = keys.reduce<FormsMap>((result, key) => {`
typescript undesturd result[key] as a undefined possibility, e.g. if you find an unknow key , thats return never, if you have a defined explicit keys, you should create a type or enum for match for this key. Otherise I suggest you avoid set value in array, insteread you use an Map type for this.

Comment: but typescript know what `key` is `keyof of  InitialState`. So obviosly `result[key]` exist in `FormsMap`

Comment: >Otherise I suggest you avoid set value in array, insteread you use an Map type for this. <
Are you speaking about `keys` array?

Comment: No i speaking about Map object for find specific key.

'but typescript know what key is keyof of  InitialState. So obviosly result[key] exist in FormsMap ' -> in this case initialState is an object and not have explicit type, so it's is a ```any``` type, and ```any``` is a never equivalent.

you should try write type definition for InitialState, something like

```
type InitialStateType  = {
 login: {login: string , password: string, accepted_terms: boolean}
  forgot: {
    login: string,
    password: password,
  },
}
```

Comment: And i assumed to you try inplement form and login global state in react or something like , I suggest you separate form state f=from login state, using things like custonhooks or redux

Comment: not `initialState` not any. you can check it.

Comment: >not initialState not any. you can check it

but if you need to use key  for read, you should need define type for object. Just try.


just another thing

````type FormsMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? `forms.${K}` : never
}
```` maybe extract key as a string type cause this, because key extract not work like this

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const InitialState = {
  login: {
    login: '',
    password: '',
    accept_terms: false,
  },
  forgot: {
    login: '',
    password: '',
  },
}

type FormsMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends string ? `forms.${K}` : never
}

const getForms = <T>(state: T) => {
  const result: Record<string, any> = {}
  Object.entries(state).forEach(([key]) => {
    result[key] = `forms.${key}`
  })
  return result as FormsMap<T>
}

const forms = getForms(InitialState)
// type forms = {
//   forgot: "forms.forgot"
//   login: "forms.login"
// }

export default forms
```

Comment: intresting solution, but types `getForms` doen't work well, because we just mark Record as FormsMap, but there isn't any check by types. for example `result[key] = 'notForms'` - is ok in this code.