# How to define the union key of an object when clone itself

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
interface A{
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

const a: A = {a: 'a', b: 1};
const b: A = {a: 'aa', b: 2};
Object.keys(a).forEach((key)=>{
    a[key as keyof A] = b[key as keyof A];
})
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG8BQyfLgLmQGcwpQBzAbm1wCNCQBXAW1umoF9NMEB7EEnkKpkAXmToCyAORxpAGmT1kARg7U+AsEuFiJU2XMXKATOswB5WgCsICMADoA1hACeRABRwAlA5i8oAFFEAAsPDxdXb1EAPixcPABtSLwiZEjeGDQAXT1aZLdU9LdMnM5vIA

Comment: What is meant by union key? Please add more details

Comment: I'd willing to bet that it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189542/typescript-why-cant-i-assign-a-valid-field-of-an-object-with-type-a-a-b/68190097#68190097)

Comment: @TusharShahi Sorry for my poor description, click the link, you can see an error on the right side.